# Text To Speech is not working in CountDownTimer

Tags: android, eclipse, text-to-speech

Hey all, so I'm trying to run Text-to-speech once one of my timers is at 10 seconds. However, it isn't saying anything when the timer reaches 10 seconds.

```
package com.android.countdown;


import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class countdown extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
    CountDownTimer Counter1;
    CountDownTimer Counter2;
    CountDownTimer Counter3;
    int Interval = 1;
    TextToSpeech tts;

    public String formatTime(long millis) {
          String output = "0:00";
          long seconds = millis / 1000;
          long minutes = seconds / 60;

          seconds = seconds % 60;
          minutes = minutes % 60;


          String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
          String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);

          if (seconds < 10)
            secondsD = "0" + seconds;
          if (minutes < 10)
            minutesD = "0" + minutes;

          output = minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
          return output;
        }

      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);




//Declare Start/Stop timer
    Button btnstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
    Button btnstop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstop);

//Text field to show time left
    final TextView mCounter1TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter1);
    final TextView mCounter2TextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter2);
    final TextView mCounter3TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter3);


//Counter 1
Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(20000 , Interval) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
    mCounter1TextField.setText("Seconds remaining: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
    if (millisUntilFinished == 10000) {
        countdown1speech();
    }


}

public void onFinish() {
    Counter1.start();  
}
};



}

      public void countdown1speech() {
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            tts.speak("You have 10 seconds remaining", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

        }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

My onTick() is nested inside an object instantiation for my countdown timer. So I'm not able to put my

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
tts.speak("You have 10 seconds remaining", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

in there without getting an error..But I'm not sure why the speech isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize TTS within your activities `onCreate()` or `onResume()` method. See also [How to wait for TextToSpeech initialization on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141567/how-to-wait-for-texttospeech-initialization-on-android/4809630#4809630)

Comment: Thanks! I have initialized it inside onCreate(). However I have 1 small problem.. if I leave  if (millisUntilFinished == 10000)    Then the speech won't come up. But if I change it to  if (millisUntilFinished < 10000)    The speech will come up but it will (obviously) keep repeating when the timer is below 10 seconds. Do you know why it can't detect the 10 second interval exactly? And is there a way around this? At first I thought it was the interval being set to 1, so I changed it to 1000 and it still didn't work

Comment: My guess is that the timer is not called at millisecond resolution (hardware dependent probably) and thus onTick() could be called at e.g. 10004 and then at 9994 when the resolution is e.g. 10ms

Comment: Thank you very much. I decided to add if (millisUntilFinished < 10999) {    if (millisUntilFinished > 9999) {   until i can figure out another way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't see how your timer even starts in the first place. You don't start it until you've finished! You have:

```
public void onFinish() {
    Counter1.start();  
}
```

The .start(); should be after the closing brace of the instantiation of the CountDownTimer

It would help a lot if you formatted your code properly and got rid of the redundant stuff like the buttons

Comment: I have that set there so that the timer resets and starts again when it reaches 0. It's a special kind of timer ; )

Comment: I also did not include the whole code. The timer starts when a button is pressed.