# wait till TextToSpeech onInit() has been initialized

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-service, text-to-speech

I am developing a simple app which will speak the contact name or an unknown number when call is received. I am implementing the app using `broadcastReceiver` and `Services`. If i run the app on `emulator` and start the call using `DDMS`, with 2 or 3 contacts saved, the app works fine since `onInit()` is called before `tts.speak()` runs.

Now when i try to run the same app on my android phone, `onInit` is called after the `tts.speak()`. From what i have understood while searching for an answer to this question, this happens due to `tts.speak()` not waiting for `onInit` to called.

One solution i found on this question was on [How to wait for TextToSpeech initialization on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141567/how-to-wait-for-texttospeech-initialization-on-android) but that didn't work either.

This question has been asked a lot of times but i couldn't find a working solution. This link suggested to use handler http://davidcheney.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/multitasking-in-android/ but being a newbie i have no idea as to how to implement that.

From what i understood i have to wait till `onInit` is called before i can use `tts.speak()` but i don't know how to do it.

**Update**
I was trying to call `speak` function outside the `onInit` since the data which was to be spoken was coming from elsewhere and i didn't want to do all the coding in `onInit`,this was not working. So i changed my code and finally somehow managed to run that `speak()` inside `onInit()`. 
Although the code is now running but there must be a way to call `speak()` outside `onInit`. So i will wait for a better answer else post my code for others facing same problem.

Comment: See my anwser to similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141567/how-to-wait-for-texttospeech-initialization-on-android

Comment: Please take a look to the solution I posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23786730/447558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either set a class member flag `boolean mTtsInitialized` and check this flag everytime you call `speak` or put the code to get the data to be spoken in `onInit`

Comment: I don't wanna put data in onInit(). I have used the boolean flag thing. But what condition should i put? if `(mTtsInitialized==true)` then what? how should i wait for `mTtsInitialized` to be true that is the main problem.

Comment: You set mTtsInitialized = true in onInit if the status is TextToSpeech.SUCCESS. Then if (mTtsInitialized) { speak(...) };

Comment: I am using `(mTtsInitialized) { speak(...) };` in entirely different function i.e. not in `onInit` thus it sees that `mTtsInitialized` is `false` so no `speak` is called.

Comment: That is because onInit has not been called and thus mTtsInitialized is false. Post your relevant codes.

Comment: Code is long so it is difficult to post. Is there any way using `Thread` or `AsyncTask` by which we can wait for one task to finish then execute other or to pause a task until first task is finished.

Comment: The system called onInit so you do not know when it will be called. That is why I suggested that you fetch your data in onInit. Can you describe the sequence of what your app is trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to make a caller calling app. I am implementing most of my coding in Service. in `onCreate()` in am doing the following 1. initializing tts 2. checking `phoneStateListener` if phone is ringing 3. if ringing, comparing the contacts for a possible match 4. If matched, calling `speak()` speaking the name else speaking number

Comment: Register your phone state listener in onInit. That is put mTelManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); in onInit

Comment: ok i think i understand what you are trying to do. Just one question is it necessary to call speak() through `onInit` only?

Comment: No, you can call speak anywhere as long as onInit has been called

Comment: and how can we be sure that we wait till `onInit` has been initialized?

Comment: It hard to explain, but as the example above. My code will call speak in my phone state listener so I have to register the listener in onInit. So that as long as onInit has not been called, there will be no phone state listener.

Comment: ya i understood that. It is same as calling speak() from `onInit`. Thanks for answering. I will wait to see some other answers before marking the answer as solved.

Comment: Unless you keep destroy and recreate the TextToSpeech, onInit is only called once. Thus calling speak inside onInit is a bad idea. It is better that you should move most of your code in onCreate to onInit.

Comment: i destroy tts after phone ringing stops so that is not a problem.

Comment: I would not destroy and recreate the TextToSpeech every time the phone state listener is called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33592/discussion-between-rohan-kandwal-and-hoan-nguyen)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most elegant way of handling this, I'm sure, but could you extend the class containing the onInit() method?

In this class, you could have a boolean variable that effectively "locks" your thread.  Override the onInit() method, call super(), and then after super() set this value to true.  Then, enter a loop that blocks the thread which calls tts.speak() until this value is true.

You'll want to keep in mind that you can't do this in the UI thread, because if you block that for too long it will crash your app.

I hope I understood your question correctly.  :)

Comment: please provide a small example for me to understand better